# SimpleCursorAdapter with cursor (Android ContentProvider)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, cursor

My activity :

```
package com.tutos.android.content.provider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import com.tutos.android.content.provider.SharedInformation.*;


public class ContentProviderExempleActivity extends Activity {
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    ListView listview;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_provider_exemple);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        insertRecords();
        displayContentProvider();

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void displayContentProvider() {


        String ColumnsCur[] = new String[]{Cours._id,Cours.COURS_NAME,Cours.COURS_DESC};
        int toViews[] = new int[]{R.id._id,R.id.Name,R.id.Desc};
        Uri mContact = AndroidProvider.CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(mContact, ColumnsCur, null, null, null);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cur,ColumnsCur,toViews,0);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void insertRecords() {

        //On crée un ContentValue, puis on appelle la méthode getContentResolver pour récupérer
        //une instance de ContentProvider, puis on appelle la méthode insert avec l’uri et les valeurs à insérer.
        ContentValues contact = new ContentValues();
        contact.put(Cours.COURS_NAME,"Android");
        contact.put(Cours.COURS_DESC,"Introduction à la programmation sous Android");
        getContentResolver().insert(AndroidProvider.CONTENT_URI,contact);

        //on vide le contentValue avant de réinserrer
        contact.clear();
        contact.put(Cours.COURS_NAME,"Java");
        contact.put(Cours.COURS_DESC,"Introduction à la programmation Java");
        getContentResolver().insert(AndroidProvider.CONTENT_URI,contact);

        contact.clear();
        contact.put(Cours.COURS_NAME, "Iphone");
        contact.put(Cours.COURS_DESC, "Introduction à l'objectif C");
        getContentResolver().insert(AndroidProvider.CONTENT_URI, contact);
    }
```

My Main Activity Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ContentProviderExempleActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My name_item_desc_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/_id"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.23" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.23" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Desc"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.23" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This think is driving me crazy :) after launching my App , the ListView is empty, notice that my cursor is full and i did use Log.i to check his content and he contains the database.

I've looked up a lot but each tutorial has his own way to do it and in android documentation i found this example that i used but still nothing + there is so much change in Android API that i'm kind of lost :)

Can you help please ? :)

Comment: Can you post `R.layout.simple_list_item_1`?

Answer (score 0):

The view which has a weight specified should set the specific attribute (height or width) to 0, so android system measures the view.

Since item's `LinearLayout` has orientation `horizontal`, it means that the 3 `TextView`s will appear in a single line, sharing the width. That means the width of all `TextView`s should be set to `0dp`.

If you want them placed in a column, change the orientation to `vertical` and height to `0dp`.

---

Next your `ListView`'s height and width are `wrap_content` which means that the contents will be measured by android. For performance I'd recommend using width `match_parent` and height `wrap_content` so the item layout is calculated based on it's content.

Comment: i changed as you suggested my two layout files : 
    `<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: and : 
`<TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/_id"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.23" />`

but still nothing on the list view :(